# Use PHP to submit HTTP POST request containing image

Tags: php

So I've seen many examples of uploading an image via PHP using move_uploaded_file, but from the way that sounds, that would be a PHP script that resides on the server. In my case, I'm not trying to handle an uploaded file. I'm trying to submit a POST request and actually have the binary content of the file inserted with the HTTP POST request.

For example, my PHP script should be able to submit a form and include an image in its HTTP POST data, but I can't seem to figure this out or find valid examples specifically for doing this.

To further clarify, I am using CURL within PHP to submit this multipart/form-data.

Here's an example of what I have now:

```
function GetPostData($filename) {
    if(!$filename) {
        echo "The image doesn't exist ".$filename;
    } else {
        $data = [
            'device_timestamp' => time(), 
            'photo' => '@'.$filename
        ];
        return $data;
    }
}
function SendRequest($url, $post, $data, $userAgent, $cookies) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://i.example.com/api/v1/'.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://192.168.1.21:8080');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    if($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    if($cookies) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');            
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    }

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return [
        'code' => $http, 
        'response' => $response,
    ];
}
```

.

```
 $data = GetPostData($filename);
        $post = SendRequest('media/upload/', true, $data, $agent, true);
```

But when I submit the image via the PHP script, this is what it looks like when I inspect the network traffic.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------eee3f953c516cc55
Connection: close

--------------------------eee3f953c516cc55
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device_timestamp"

1491023582
--------------------------eee3f953c516cc55
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"

@/home/user/Desktop/square.jpeg
--------------------------eee3f953c516cc55--
```

Isn't the POST data supposed to contain the binary output of the image? How would the server save the image otherwise if just the path of the file is submitted in the form and not the actual image?

In other words, just like you would go to the terminal and type `cat image.jpg`, that's what I need PHP to submit in its form.

Comment: Please check this  : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: This is what I'm talking about. That tutorial uses move_uploaded_file. Isn't that that moving an uploaded file from a CLIENT's POST request and placing it into a specific area on the server? I'm not trying to do that. I'm trying to be the client that submits the HTTP POST request containing the image.

Comment: Can you share your all code ?

Comment: Niklesh all codes are there

Comment: Can You say me You want to save path of image in database ?

Comment: I don't want to save the image path. I want to submit the image in its binary format. The server on the other end (not mine) takes the binary and saves it as an image, so I need to submit the binary output and not the file path.

Comment: @niklesh That codes are work You have not understand can you ask me again .

Comment: @LewlSauce : if your site name is `www.abc.com` make folder `image` in inside root folder of public folder and save file over there, and about path it would something like `www.abc.com/image/first_image.jpg`

Comment: @Niklesh I think there's still a misunderstanding. I have zero control over anything on the destination server. The destination server is simply saving whatever the value of "picture" as something.jpg. So therefore I need to submit a form that says picture=<raw image data>

Comment: If you can update `.php` file you have in full control.

Comment: This PHP file is simply the client submitting the image. move_uploaded_file takes what a client submitted and then relocates it on the destination server. I'm not trying to do that. Is there not a simple way to make PHP do something equivalent to `cat image.jpg` and use that as its a value in the POST data?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem by changing

```
 function GetPostData($filename) {
        if(!$filename) {
            echo "The image doesn't exist ".$filename;
        } else {
            $data = [
                'device_timestamp' => time(), 
                'photo' => '@'.$filename
            ];
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
 function GetPostData($filename) {
        if(!$filename) {
            echo "The image doesn't exist ".$filename;
        } else {
            $data = [
                'device_timestamp' => time(), 
                'photo' => file_get_contents($filename)
            ];
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have required to use in  then you can easly uploded image

ex:-

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

---

PHP Code Required

```
 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
            $filename=$_FILES['Yourfilename']['name'];
            $filetempname=$_FILES['Yourfilename']['tmp_name'];
            $fname=md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].rand()).$filename;
            $filepath1="uploads/folder name/".$fname;
            move_uploaded_file($filetempname,$filepath1);
    ?>
```

Comment: I updated my question for clarification. I still think this move_uploaded_file is intended to be placed in the PHP script on the destination server. I don't have control over the destination server. The server is expecting the raw image data to be submitted in the multipart/form-data and not the actual file path, and I am the client trying to submit that.